# Gem configuration in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to use some gems that require to apply some changes in the initial configuration.

In [this](https://github.com/justintv/APNS) particular gem it says I have to change the configuration parameters. Where do I find this in ruby 1.9 and rails 3

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put that code anywhere -- if it's setting up and configuring objects that will be used throughout your app and you want it run when the app starts, you can put it in an initializer. **config/initializers/APNS.rb**

Comment: I have copied the configuration settings suggested in the gem's readme file but I get ".../APNs.rb:27:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant APNS (NameError)" when I try to run the server

Comment: try to look inside your .rvm/ directory for the source code of that gem -- typically there is an examples directory there

Comment: a good place to experiment is in the rails console -- you can see what series of commands will get you the environment you want